# Event handling inside stateless functional components in React, Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, event-handling

I have an `onClick` event in one of my functional components:

```
import * as React from 'react';

const BreadCrumbs: React.SFC<{level: Array<string>, changeLevel: Function}> = ({level, changeLevel}) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          level.map(function(elem, i) { 
            return <span key={i} onClick={changeLevel}>{elem}</span> 
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
}

export default BreadCrumbs;
```

In the parent component I supply the `<BreadCrumbs>` component with props of an array and a function reference:

```
<BreadCrumbs level={this.state.levels} changeLevel={this.changeLevel}/>
```

This doesn't work because in the `<BreadCrumbs>` component, the Typescript compiler fails with the error (on `return <span>` line):

```
[ts]
Type '{ key: number; onClick: Function; children: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>'.
  Type '{ key: number; onClick: Function; children: string; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>'.
    Types of property 'onClick' are incompatible.
      Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLSpanElement>) => void) | undefined'.
        Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLSpanElement>) => void'.
          Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLSpanElement>): void'.
(JSX attribute) onClick: Function
```

However, if I modify my code to this:

```
const BreadCrumbs: React.SFC<{level: Array<string>, changeLevel: Function}> = ({level, changeLevel}) => {
    function something(i: number) {
      changeLevel(i);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {
          level.map(function(elem, i) { 
            return <span key={i} onClick={something.bind(this, i)}>{elem}</span> 
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
}

export default BreadCrumbs;
```

Everything works fine.
Why doesn't the first version work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript, it use a strongly typed manner to perform type checking on functions, which takes the parameters and returned value of a function into consideration. Thus, for the parameter (React component prop) `changeLevel`, its type should be declared as `(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLSpanElement>) => void` or compatible types (like `(e: React.MouseEvent<Element>) => void`, `() => void`, or `() => any`). The `Function` type is not used for function type declaration, but for typing the global constructor of any function object, which lacks the information about function object and should be avoided when typing a function.

You can change your code to following version to pass TypeScript's checking.

```js
const BreadCrumbs: React.SFC<{level: Array<string>, changeLevel: () => void}> = ({level, changeLevel}) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          level.map(function(elem, i) { 
            return <span key={i} onClick={changeLevel}>{elem}</span> 
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
}
```

Actually, in the second version, the return type of `bind` function is `any`, which can be assigned to variable of any type in TypeScript. TypeScript performs no type checking in that version.